# nodejs couldn't execute the jar file

Tags: node.js, jar

```
var child = exec('java -jar entrance.jar', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
// console.log("1111");
const data = stdout;
console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
if(error !== null){
  console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}
```

});

When with the suffix `.jar`,I got nothing without a little log.

When without the suffix `.jar`,I get the error below:
`stdout:
 stderr:Error: Unable to access jarfile`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc4Jv.png)

please help me~